# How to show this long input with prepend in Mobile which allows user to choose url name?

Tags: forms, mobile, input, responsive-design, mobile-first

I'm working on a responsive website where I need to inform users that information he will fill in input will be used to create url for his campaign he is going to create.

That input looks like this.

[image]

This is fine in Desktop but in Mobile screen with 320px screen width it's doesn't fit. What could be best possible option to convey that same information in small screen.

**Note: I'm making a responsive website where I use same HTML so I can't provide a totally different HTML to mobile. I can only make changes by detecting screen size using CSS media queries.**

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider just providing an input for the user to insert their desired campaign name, and underneath it have a bound paragraph (like in Angular) displaying in a small font the complete URL, updating as the user types.

You can easily implement it with a bit of jQuery and on/keydown or have it built-in in any Javascript webapp framework.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you break it over multiple lines at small resoultions?
Treat the first (grey) section as a label, and set the input field left aligned under it.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnnURa.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

That should be possible with just CSS, so long as you've marked up the grey box as a label element in the html and not as an input element.